# How can I subtract a day(s) using dt.timedelta(days =7) including month changes?

Tags: python, datetime

I am automating a process that needs data from at the most 3 days prior. How do I deal with month changes because the code below doesn't seem to recognize the month change? It will go back to the first of the new month and stop there.

```
today = dt.date.today().strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
preDay = (dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```

I put `days=7` just to see what it would do and it will not enter the previous month.

```
pol       airs          Date    so2  wspeed    wdir
99   482331073  202011010000   0.18    4.87   31.78
100  482331073  202011010100   0.15    3.26   50.83
101  482331073  202011010200   0.17    1.45  312.37
102  482331073  202011010300   0.14    4.51  272.41
103  482331073  202011010400   0.15    5.25  256.48
```

I need data from all the way to 20201030.

How might I deal with the month change?

Comment: We're at the start of November, and by running your code, I get `preDay` = `'10-26-2020'`, which is last month as expected. What goes wrong in your code is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

By using `strftime("%m-%d-%Y")` you're creating a string that is in the wrong order for comparison.  Use the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format `"%Y-%m-%d"` if you insist on comparing strings.